# How to debug unstable internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I have a following setup:

- Laptop uses home internet through WiFi, and the WiFi router sits in another room.
- The Wifi router itself uses cellural internet to connect to the outside world.

Most of the times everything works. But, when it doesn't, then I am basically without internet connection and all the new tabs in Chrome will fail to load. After hitting refresh one to few times and waiting 10-120 seconds, the tab finds internet connection again.

#### Details

- I measured the internet connection speed with two different websites, the download speeds were 60-100Mbs, Upload speeds 40Mbs, and ping 20-30ms. This of course is when there is no interruption.
- The problem exists with every device connected to the WiFi, not just this one. (this is Windows 10 laptop, but I'm looking for a general solution)
- The problem exists only randomly, and there is no way to reproduce it.

#### Question

I'm looking for a way to find the root cause to the problem. Since the problem is not reproducible, I guess I should setup logging for something, but for what?

Comment: The router might have an option for keeping logs of events.

Comment: Please check if this article was helpful: [How to Troubleshoot Your Internet Connection, Layer-By-Layer](https://www.howtogeek.com/231887/htg-explains-how-to-troubleshoot-your-internet-connection/).

Answer (score 0):

Does your main router have an Ethernet port? Most do. When Internet is out, hook up to the Ethernet port to verify the outage.

From there you need to place a Service Call with the ISP.

It may be your gear, but the ISP can help you with this. Otherwise it is up to the ISP.

It may be a bit onerous to keep a PC connected by Ethernet but they will want this information or without it may just blame you.

I did look at my own Router Logging, but it does not log external events (loss of Internet at the Modem).

Comment: Thanks for you input. There is an Ethernet port, but the problem usually goes go quickly away that even if I would run to the other room, and plug it with Ethernet wire, everything is working just fine. That could be the case even if I was sitting next to the router. I wish I could just log something and then see from the logs what specifically was wrong - or to use the logs for screening out possible reasons, at least.

Comment: It may be a bit onerous, but try keeping a computer hooked up to narrow down the problem. The ISP will want this information.

Answer (score -1):

I have infrequent 'Your internet connection is unstable' popups when playing on-line bridge on BBO.  BBO generates these popups.  Their system constantly checks for my presence and drops me if internet connection is lost for more than a few seconds.  My setup is similar to np8's, with cable modem and separate AC router at one end of the house, my laptop at the other end, about 40 ft away with four walls in between.  Small house 1700ft, four drywall/2x4 walls between router and laptop.  Not the ideal arrangement for wifi, I know.  ISP is Spectrum cable, they came out and couldn't find any problems between their modem and their system.  Found 'Wifi Analyzer' app by Matt Hafner.  I had been using 2.4G wireless but Wifi Analyzer showed there's a lot of traffic on all of the 2.4G channels, so I switched my laptop to 5G and found a quiet channel on that band.  That helped noticeably but didn't completely cure the problem.  My 5G signal strength is around -55 dB, not sure what minimum signal should be.  With 5G, I run speed tests and normally get better than 200Mb/s with my laptop so this isn't a 'speed' problem, it an intermittent disruption problem.  The unstable internet problem always corrects itself within a few seconds.  I've noticed the events seem to occur when my Trane furnace's VSD blower kicks on.  I haven't noticed anything else triggering the events.  I'm thinking it is VSD-induced noise in home's AC wiring causing radio-frequency electromagnetic interference with the wi-fi signal.  Asked my furnace installer about this - they hadn't heard of it before so they tapped into nationwide network of service people - the only reply was a possible defective choke on the VSD motor wiring.  They want $140 to come out and look.  I don't see how a choke could go bad, but may try that at some point.  The modem & router were on a 3-wire 120/240 circut that shared a neutral with the furnace so I put fed them with an extension cord from another circuit, didn't help.  I bought a 250VA isolation transformer for the modem and router, didn't help.  I added a small ferrite core on the hot wire feeding the furnace, that didn't help.  Considering a small APC 600VA UPS for $70 for the modem & router, but not sure an inexpensive UPS really provides clean AC power.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't vandalize your answer. If you want to delete it, there is a "delete" button below your answer that you can use. If you want to edit it, you need to make it more clear, not vandalize it.